# Where can I get dataset to identify male and female flower of any plant?

Tags: dataset, photo

I've tried many sites but none of them has got dataset to identify male and female flowers. Can anyone help me to fine dataset to identify male and female flowers of any plant?

Comment: This question is more suitable on opendata.stackexchange.com

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.